# Escribir más de un registro por archivo en psql con psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo un bot con selenium y psycopg2 que recoge datos para hacer un backup y guardarlo en una base de datos psql pero solo me sube un solo archivo y quiero que me suba cada un archivo que esté en la carpeta (suelen haber mas de 100 archivos).

```py
for url in names:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)

    try:
        title = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'title').click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print('Someone is editing there... truncating')
        continue

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").perform()
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("c").perform()    
    title = root.clipboard_get()
    title = title.replace(' ', '-')
    title = title.replace('|', '')
    title = title.replace('®', '')
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'fusion_toggle_builder').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'content_ifr').click()
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("a").perform()
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("c").perform()
    shortcode = root.clipboard_get()
    f = open(url_site+'/shortcodes/'+title+'_shortcode.txt', '+w', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(shortcode)
    f.close()
    route=url_site+'/shortcodes/'+title+'_shortcode.txt'
    print("successful connection")
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    query_shortcoder=cursor.execute('SELECT ID FROM objects WHERE filename=%s AND objectType=0',vars=[url_site])
    row=cursor.fetchone()
    id=row[0]
    print(id)
    inspect_shortcoder=cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM objects WHERE parentId=%s AND objectType=1',vars=[id])
    rows=cursor.fetchall()
    print(rows)
    if len(rows)==0:
        whrite_shortcoder=cursor.execute('INSERT INTO objects(id ,parentId, objectType, fileLocation, fileName) VALUES(DEFAULT ,%s, %s, %s, %s)',vars_list=[(id,1,route,title)])
        connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera
cambié

```
if len(rows)>=0:
    whrite_shortcoder=cursor.execute('INSERT INTO objects(id ,parentId, objectType, fileLocation, fileName) VALUES(DEFAULT ,%s, %s, %s, %s)',[id,1,route,title])
    connection.commit()
```